# Composer cannot find path repo - Laravel spark

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-spark

So, Laravel spark isn't letting me connect to the github any more and it's causing me to be unable to push to heroku and completely halting my work. I tried placing the spark code in a folder and then making the code path repository. However, when I run composer update it still tries to fetch the code from the same github location. Seems like it isn't finding the repo.

I have tried tons of path variations and placing the code in various locations. Here is the section from the composer:

```
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "laravel/spark":"*",
....

    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "vendor/laravel/spark"
        },    
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://spark-satis.laravel.com"
        }
    ],
```

And, in the package composer ...

```
"name": "laravel/spark",
"description": "Laravel Spark provides scaffolding for Laravel SaaS applications.",
"keywords": ["laravel", "stripe", "billing", "scaffolding", "saas"],
"license": "MIT",
"authors": [
    {
        "name": "Taylor Otwell",
        "email": "taylorotwell@gmail.com"
    }
],
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "erusev/parsedown": "~1.0",
    "firebase/php-jwt": "~3.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
    "ramsey/uuid": "^3.1",
    "intervention/image": "^2.3"
},
"require-dev": {
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.0",
    "mpociot/vat-calculator": "^1.6"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Laravel\\Spark\\": "src/"
    }
},
"extra": {
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.0-dev"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "dev"
```

Is there something that I am missing to ensure that composer uses the path repo instead of looking at github?

Answer (score 1):

Push laravel/spark code to your own git repo, than inside composer.json use

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://path to your repo"
    }
],
```

and run `composer require laravel/spark`, It should take the code from your repo

Answer (score 1):

Since laravel/spark is not free anymore and cannot be installed or updated with composer

You have to purchase license version to use it.

https://spark.laravel.com/licenses